# How to get declaring KtFile/KtClass using KtCallExpression?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

I'm using kotlin compiler to analyze kotlin source file and I need to get where the method is defined using `KtCallExpression`.
`KtCallExpression` in question is retrieved from method call.

For better explanation, here's example, if there's source file named `Main.kt` with contents:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    f1()
    Test.f2()
}

fun f1() {
}

class Test {
    companion object {
        fun f2() {
        }
    }
}
```

when analyzing function `main`, it will produce 2 `KtCallExpression`, one for `f1()` and other for `f2()`
However I'm not sure how to get file `Main.kt` from `KtCallExpression` for `f1()`, or class `Test` from `KtCallExpression` for `f2()`

I tried to look for its documentations, however Kotlin compiler doesn't contain enough docs. I've also tried bunch of auto completion suggested by Intellij Idea but none of those doesn't seem to lead me to original declaration.

Comment: Seems like BindingContext has something to do with this, although I'm unsure where to learn more about it. If it's really the solution, could anyone link me to documentation?